# Core graphics using too much CPU

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation

I am implementing the following graphics drawRect function but it uses more than 50% of the CPU - any idea on how I could solve that? I just draw a few random lines, but I want that they all have a different width.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [super drawRect:rect];

    @autoreleasepool {

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();



        float width = rect.size.width;
        int nbLine=10; // i want to draw 10 paths

        for (int iLine=1;iLine<nbLine;iLine++){

            float Pathwidth=0.8*(nbLine-(float)iLine)/nbLine;
            CGContextBeginPath(context);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, Pathwidth); //each path should have its own width
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0,0);

            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                float x=width/(i+1);
                float y=1;//for this example, I just put a fixed number here - it's normally an external variable
                CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, x+width/10, y,  x,0);


            }

            CGContextAddPath(context, path);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
        }

        CGPathRelease(path);

    }
}
```

thank you !

Comment: drawing should max the CPU. how long does the drawing take?

Comment: Is there a reason you have the `@autoreleasepool`?

Comment: no reason for the @autoreleasepool (just a test). It's really fast to draw and it's correctly updated at each cycle (every 4ms I believe)

Comment: What changes in the cycle?  Why redraw every frame?

Comment: Because at each cycle, `float y=1` is actually updated by a new value (I have simplified for the example)

Comment: So you are saying that your y value changes 250 times per second (every 4ms)?  I'm not sure how your code is working, but would it be possible to update only when the y value changes?

Comment: my mistake, it was set at every 40 ms and not 4ms, and still killing the CPU. The y value changes at the same speed. What seems to cost the most is the fact that each line has to have a different width.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try.

1. Use instruments to find out exactly which line(s) are using the CPU.
2. Build the path in a UIBezierPath once and then draw them each time in drawRect.
3. Look at where setNeedsDisplay is being called from.  Most likely each time it draws it isn't using up too much CPU.  It is very possible that the problem is that it is rapidly drawing over and over.

Comment: - each path is different (actually just an homothety of the other paths). Then the setNeedsDisplay is called like that: - (void)startDisplayLink
    {
        _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
        [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }

    - (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
    {
        
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you are pressed for performance you can use a GLKView.  Core Drawing is based in OpenGL with a whole bunch of optimizations set for graphical clarity and quality.  But if those options are slowing you down to the point of non-usability then that may be your best bet.

My second suggestion would be to not call the draw so often.  You said it gets called every 4 ms which is 250 times per second.  The user can't see that fine of detail, so that is extravagant.

My third suggestion is to use a UIView, draw once, then modify it's transform based on your y variable.  It appears as though you could do a simple y scaling to achieve what you are trying to do (no x changes, no width of line changes (after drawing it once)).  I could be over simplifying based on your code, but it would be a good thing to try.  You could also do a mix of this suggestion and your code and redraw if the y scale transform becomes too large.

Comment: my mistake, it was set at every 40 ms and not 4ms, and still killing the CPU... I am more worried by the app killing the battery... I will try for the UIView trick - however what seems to cost the most CPU is the fact that each patch must have a different width...